# Signal from QML to C++ slot, cannot find the QML signal

Tags: qt, qml, signals-slots, qtquick2

I got a signal in QML and I want to connect to a slot defined in C++. However my code is failing and I'm receiving the error:

> QObject::connect: No such signal QDeclarativeContext::sent() in ../qt_cpp/mainwindow.cpp:66

Here is a c++ code snippet:

```
message_reading test;
QDeclarativeView tempview;
tempview.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/media_screen.qml"));
QObject *item = tempview.rootContext();
QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(sent()),
&test, SLOT(readMediaJSONDatabase(QString&)));
```

And here is a QML code snippet:

```
Image {
    id: bluetooth
    source: "images_mediahub/footer_icons/bluetooth_normal.png"
    signal sent(string msg)
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill:  parent
        onClicked: {
            bluetooth.sent(Test.medialibrarydb.toString())
            info_load.source="./bluetooth.qml"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SIGNAL` macro call in the `connect` line must inform the parameter explicitly, with `SIGNAL(sent(QString))`.

In addition, the signal is being emitted by the created object, but code snippet you provided is trying to connect it in the context object instead. You'll need something along the lines of:

```
QObject *tempitem = tempview.rootObject();
```

There's a [complete example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#connecting-to-qml-signals) covering that in the documentation.

Comment: No, I tried to add type SIGNAL(sent(QString)) there, and it not working. report same error message BTW, compile success, but when open the application window, then return this error message.

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I notice you're also trying to attach it to the context, which isn't what you want. Will update the answer.

Comment: thank you anyway. I got some new update... but still learning this .

Comment: Your update actually asks a different question. I believe the two points in the answer actually solve your original one.